# Problem with math \complement, MinionPro and Mnsymbol packages

Tags: math-operators, mathtools, minionpro, mnsymbol

I have a problem with `\complement` command. Instead the expect output for this command appears the output for `\lcirclerightint`. I'm usign `MinionPro` packages which loads automatically `MnSymbol`. I suspect that there are conflict between `mathtools` and `MnSymbol` packages. Here is example of my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[amsbb,minionint,lf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{theoremref}
\usepackage{scalerel} 
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\DeclareMathOperator{\intt}{int}

\begin{document}
Sea $A=\complement\overline{X}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are any way to fix this?

Comment: Does it happen if you only load `MnSymbol` instead of `MinionPro`?

Comment: @egreg No. ....

Comment: Well, not to me.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. you are right.

Comment: @egreg the problem is `minionint` option of `MinionPro` package.